# I would like to auto update a field using parsed data from another?

Tags: field-update

I am trying to either set up a field that will auto populate with parsed data from another or a workflow to accomplish the same.

I have text field of Field1_*C with data 12345D.  I would like to pull the first five digits (12345) and paste into Field2*_C with "ABCDE" appended to the front.  Result should look like "ABCDE12345".

Every formula I try says "Field1__C may not be used in this type of formula".  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the actual formula-- any version that you've tried so far? And what is the context of this formula?

Comment: Can you paste what formula(s) you have tried? This is a Workflow Field Update, and both Field1__c and Field2__c are on the same obect, and that object is selected for the field update, correct?

Comment: Actually, I found my issue.  I created Field2__C as a text field instead of formula.  Once I realized my problem, end result formula was: "ABCDE"+(LEFT(Field1__c, 5)).  Worked like a charm.

Comment: Can you post the problematic formula to your question, and the fixed formula as an answer so this question can be marked resolved and useful for others in the future?

Comment: ca_peterson, the problematic formula was the same as I used above.  The issue was that I was using the formula on a text field as a validation instead of creating proper WorkFlow Field Update as a Formula field.

Comment: To reiterate ca_peterson's comment, please post your answer AS AN ANSWER (below), not as a comment, so that the question can be marked as answered.

Answer (score -1):

To help show there's an answer to your question, per the comments above, the source of the issue was that @SDiv was using the formula on a text field as a validation rule instead of creating a proper WorkFlow Field Update as a Formula field.